# Mongoid Top Locations Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapreduce, mongoid

I have a `Location` model and wanna fetch the top ten countries with the most locations in it.

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :country, as: :country, type: String
  field :name, as: :name, type: String
end
```

I wanna have results like this:

1. USA
   1000 Locations
2. AUSTRIA
   500 Locations
3. GERMANY
   100 Locations

How can I achieve that with mongoid?
Do I need a map reduce?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by aggregation:

```
  @popular_countries = Location.collection.aggregate([
      {'$match' => {'country' => {'$ne' => nil}}},
      {'$group' => {'_id' => '$country',
                    'counts' => {'$sum' => 1}}}]).sort_by(&:count)
```